# Does all features belongs to Django Rest Framework available in FAST API to develop REST APIS

Tags: encryption, fastapi

I have been working in the Django rest framework since three years on wards. Recently reading about FAST API frame work. FAST API looking like a very good framework for the current REST API service development. Seems like few things are missing from FAST API which are there in django.

1. Pagination
2. class based views.
3. mock testing
4. class based views.
5. struggled allot to provide the lookup for encrypted data in the django rest framework.

Could any one help me that how can we achieve above features with FAST API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Jan 2020. FastAPI has a much smaller and different featureset to Django Rest Framework (DRF).

DRF is built on Django you have all the features Django available to you as well as convenient tools for building REST API's.

With FastAPI the framework way is more minimal it provides a simple, quick way to create and test a set of OpenAPI compatible endpoints. With a focus on speed and asynchronous style request-response handling.

However does not include ORM or migrations, admin, accounts etc and all the other 'batteries included' stuff you get with Django.

To achieve the functionality you have listed you'd right now you'd have to roll-your-own or use some pre-existing async python packages and adapt for your needs.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer. I am planing to develop lot off APIs. Can i choose fast API now?